# WebClient doing something weird with large file

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, webclient, varnish

I have a Varnish server in front of a S3 bucket. An API will generate a private URL and allow me to download private files of this bucket through the Varnish server.

Whenever I download a 500MB file directly from the bucket or through the Varnish-server in Chrome, everything works fine.

When I move the same logic to a C# WebClient (with proxy set to NULL and only sending an User Agent header), directly downloading from the bucket works fine. When I change the URL to the Varnish-server, things start to topple over... It will stop receiving the file at exactly 104.640KB every single time.

I'll get an IOException the Stream ended unexpectedly. I've tried both DownloadData, DownloadFile and their Async counterparts. It simply will never finish the download.

I've went back and forth from .NET 2.0 all the way to 4.5.1. Does anyone have a clue why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion Varnish does some really weird things with its headers. I eventually setup OpenResty (nginx+lua) and used S3CMD to sync files whenever an URL is requested in a certain way, and used LUA to make a similar system to pre-signed URL's. This turned out to work perfectly in combination with the C# WebClient, and on top of that, I can now actually see that files really come from this particular server, which is not the case if Varnish caches it.